# Cannot get Spring Boot to enable Caching

Tags: spring, caching

I am following one of the many tutorials on the web dealing with spring boot's default cache. So no Eh, hazelnut, etc, just default
spring-boot-starter-cache
dependecy.

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class myMainThing {}

@Service
public class ExportService{
//the service is autowired in a controller
@Cacheable(value="translations",
            key="{ #keyToTranslate, #lang }")
    public String translate(String keyToTranslate, String lang){

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", 
        Locale.forLanguageTag(lang));
        if (bundle == null) {
            return keyToTranslate;
        }
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()){
            String trimmedValue = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf(ExportUtils.DOT) + 1).trim();
            if (keyToTranslate.equals(trimmedValue)) {
                return bundle.getString(key);
            }
        }
        return keyToTranslate;
    }
}

@EnableCaching
public class ExportServiceTest{

@InjectMocks
    private ExportService myService;

@Test
    public void translateSuccess(){
        String value = myService.translate("KEY", "en");
        myService.translate("KEY", "en");
        myService.translate("KEY", "en");
   }
}
```

Every time I execute the test, it always takes 6 seconds, so I am sure there are 3 executions of the translate method, each taking 2 seconds, instead of the desired result of 2 seconds, for the first execution, and close to zero seconds for getting the same result out of the cache for the next two calls.

If anyone can spot what I am doing wrong, it would be of great relief.

Thanks,

Comment: And why would it be otherwise? Your test doesn't use spring to create the instance, so how should spring features be applied to it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not sure I can follow..

It might sound stupid, but what do you mean by the test does not use spring? 
The annotations on the test class are @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) , and @Import({ExportService.class}) 
Also, I access my service with postman directly., no test classes, and the export takes much longer when I use the translate function.

Comment: The `@Import` is useless as you aren't using Spring in your test, you are using Mockito. If you want this to work with Spring then use spring and use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation and `@Autowire` the service into your test.

Comment: Thank you so much!
You are right, this test was using mockito, and I had another suite of test classes with @SpringBootTest(classes = { etc . And I understand why you said I was not using spring.

Once I moved my test there and autowired the service I got the result of two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to M. Deinum , it is clear it was a false alarm.
The test class is using Mockito.
Once I moved the test to a test class using Spring, and autowired the service, the result was two seconds.